# C convert int to double in a function

Tags: c, function, int, double

Im having a problem getting the same result from math equation when I use a function.  Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int a=5, b=2;
    double c;
    c = (double) a/b;
    printf("%f\n", c);

    c = Divide(a);
    printf("%f\n", c);

    return 0;
}

int Divide(int value)
{
    return value =(double) value/2;
}
```

When I run the code I get:

```
2.500000
2.000000
```

I am trying to get 2.50000 for both.  I have tried changing the function to

```
double Divide(double value)
```

with no luck.  Im new to C and to coding in general and Im stuck.  Thanks for anyone who can help me.

Comment: `return value =(double) value/2;` performs floating-point division, resulting in `2.5`, and then assigns the value back to an `int` with truncation, returning `2`. Removing the `value = ` part will provide the intended behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What you wrote makes sense to me.  I was able to get this function to work

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems: The first have to do with the functions return type, and returning an `int` will always truncate a floating point value.

The second problem is that you don't return the result of the division, you return the value of the variable `value` after the assignment to it, and since `value` is an integer you will return the truncated value. Drop the assignment back to it: `return (double) value / 2;`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to get this function to work like I wanted with your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
int Divide(int value)
```

change to

```
double Divide(double value)
```

since your value is of type integer, so it assigns an integer value to a float which will be 2.0

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It seems in coding there are literally a millions ways to skin a cat.  I was able to get the function to work as expected with your response, and some of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Cast `a` as follows and change the return type.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main () {
   int a=5, b=2;
   double c;
   c = ((double) a)/b;
   printf("%f\n", c);

   c = Divide(a);
   printf("%f\n", c);

    return 0;
}

double Divide(int value) {
  return value = ((double)value)/2;
}
```

Comment: Casting has higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than division, so the extra parentheses doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double divide(double value) {
    return value = value/2.0;
}

int main ()
{
    double a=5.0, c;
    int b=2;

    c = (double) a/b;
    printf("%f\n", c);

    c = divide(a);
    printf("%f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```